# Angular Page Routing in Production build

Tags: javascript, angular, apache, url-routing

I am trying to implement the routing in the angular. The `PathLocationStrategy` is enabled in angular when a new project is created. The page is getting traversing as per the route normally when the application is running in the `ng serve`. After taking the build using `ng build --prod` and deployed the `dist` build code in another environment the page loads properly if the user didn't try to reload or move to the next URL. If the same is done `URL Not Found` error is displayed in the web page.

Due to Angular is an single page web application, the entire page is loaded in the user's browser and the page gets loaded dynamically based on the user action. Based on the `index.html`, the page will get loaded and displayed in the browser. The build is generating only the index.html and component related js file. So I searched in internet and found the another routing method `HashLocationStrategy`. This help the user to traverse into the page directly through URL.

Now my application wants to integrate with a gateway to perform some authentication with the user and redirect to my specific URL with the status of authentication in GET method. But the gateway is ignoring from the `#` character in the URL and the URL gets redirected to the server. I am hosting my application in Apache(HTTPD).

Any solution is available to traverse the URL directly from the user and handle the gateway response in Angular or Apache? Your suggestion will be helpful to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Do you have a rule in server to redirect all request to `index.html`?